# What exactly is wrong with this title?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, quality-filter

I am trying to ask a question with the following title:

> using 'stdin' with fread

I actually tried a variety of variations on the above and it just refused to accept any title I have come up with so far, saying it doesn't "meet quality standards".

What is wrong with this title and how can I improve it so I can post my question?

Comment: For a start, "sentences" usually start with an upper case character. For example the title of this question should be `"What exactly...?"`.

Comment: cool, upper case did it, thanks :)

Comment: as a side note though - that's a terrible rule

Comment: You think using proper grammar is terrible? If everyone would use their own grammar we'd have a hard time communicating.

Comment: No, I think that particular rule is terrible.

Comment: @eddi the particular rule is not "capitalize the first letter". It's "come up with a decent title". That the capitalization made it pass the filter doesn't mean you can't create a better title. If you do, everybody wins.

Comment: @Bart if the algo can be (as you think of it) gamed, then it's a bad algo

Comment: @eddi It's not perfect, as witnessed by the title you eventually got through. But it keeps the worst crap out.

Comment: If you're not going to put forth any effort in hitting the `Shift` key to properly capitalize, then why should we put forth any effort to help you?

Comment: lol @ people downvoting the actual question because of this meta issue

Comment: @JackManey you should really note, that *you* or anyone else who posted here for that matter is not part of the community that can help me with my `r` question. And the meta question was helped with the very first comment.

Comment: @eddi - Oh, really? How do you know that none of the people that have commented in or answered this Meta SO question are capable of helping you with your question on R?

Comment: @eddi: I think people are downvoting you here because you asked a legitimate question, but then tried to defend your bad grammar and your ill-advised title.  Meta works best when the folks who ask their questions are actually open to receiving input.

Comment: @JackManey because I know quite well who the people that can answer me with my `r` question are. @RobertHarvey - meta people downvoting this question is totally fine, but downvoting the other is very much against SO in every sense of what SO stands for

Comment: @eddi - And how do you know who this list of people are? There are new users that register Stack Overflow accounts every day. How do you know which of them are capable of answering your R questions?

Comment: @eddi Don't make assumptions about downvotes. The latest comment on your SO question might indicate it's not all that good/clear after all. Take a step back and make sure it's as good as it can be. The downvotes might well be for the actual question and not some Meta result.

Comment: @Bart I don't see any comments explaining why the question was downvoted and it has high correlation with meta downvotes

Comment: Downvotes do not require accompanying comments.

Comment: @eddi *"I don't really understand this question. What are you trying to do exactly?"* ... and then there is the downvote tooltip on questions being unclear...

Answer (score 26):

### Put your actual question in the title.

Make it the kind of title that will be meaningful to people searching for your question in Google.

It's almost certain that your question isn't really *"teach me how to use 'stdin' with fread,"*  which would be off-topic anyway.

Comment: if the rule is to make it google searchable, then the title would be "stdin fread"

Comment: Uh, no... The title would be `Is there an fread analog for read.csv(file = 'stdin', ...)`  The title needs to be what you will see as a result in the Google search, ***not what you are actually searching for in the Google search.***

Comment: riiight, because *that's* what you put in google search - my search terms before posting the question was exactly "r data.table stdin fread"

Comment: The rule is, "make it clear and sensible" not "dump some keywords" @edd

Comment: @eddi  Google search is smart enough to find your keywords inside full sentences. Otherwise, web sites would all be sporting headlines like "Obama speech Berlin jacket" or "Egypt revolution Mursi overthrow"

Comment: @eddi You might be amazed to discover how much better Google's search results are when you enter a real question.